# Links not working - Dreamweaver CS4

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, cs4, rollovers

Hey all - I don't know why my rollover links don't work now. I think it may have to do with z-index and divs being hidden.

The breadcrumbs for example:

```
<div id="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="#">Home &gt;&gt;</a> 
    <a href="#">Section Title &gt;&gt</a> 
    <a href="#">Parent Menu Item &gt;&gt;</a> 
    <a href="#">Sub-Item 1</a>
</div>
```

The last two work for some reason. You can look at the page and view the source from here:

http://cpkdesign.com/uiaustin

Thanks everyone.

Comment: -1 for not putting the relevant code in your question.  Once you fix your site, the code at the link will be useless to future readers.

Comment: and what does any of this have to do with Dreamweaver?

Comment: If you want compliant & valid code, do not rely solely on your WYSIWYG editor.  See [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcpkdesign.com%2Fuiaustin&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `div` with the `right` id, if you can give it the following css:

```
#right {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0px;
    width: 745px;
    float: left;
}
```

That should hopefully take care of your problem.

More info:

The reason why you're running into this issue is that the `right` div is overlapping your links.  The general rule is, if you're gonna start floating your elements, then keep an eye on the non-floating elements...that div is your non-floating element in a sea of floating divs.

Comment: Thanks fo your answer. When I float that div, it goes under the nav div. is there any way i can use `!important` so it stays to the left of the nav area? However that DID fix the links. Thanks a lot techno....

Comment: Looks like you've solved that problem as well (when viewed on http://cpkdesign.com/uiaustin)